# Get ASPX part out of this.Page.Request.Url

Tags: asp.net

Whats the best way to get the aspx part out of this.Page.Request.Url.

I guess I could use FileInfo but dont think this is the best way.

Comment: Do you mean the "filename" ('/foo/bar.aspx' -> 'bar.aspx') or just the extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the current filename, use:

```
Path.GetFileName(Page.Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath)
```